# Read Flat File to H2 Database using SQL

Tags: java, sql, h2, flat-file

I'll start off by saying i'm sort of new to SQL, so this question may sound stupid.

I have a Flat File with a large quantity of names stored one record per line. the Flat File is in the fore of a .txt

I was wondering If it was possible to read the flat file and import it into the H2 Database I am using in embedded mode using SQL. I know H2 supports CSV read and write but it would be a hassle to convert the flat file to CSV every time I get a new batch of data in a flat file format.

Comment: What is the format of each line?  How are the different fields of a record separated?

Comment: simple strings one each line, not very long. This is to fill only one column

Comment: You could use `java.io.LineNumberReader` to read the file line by line, and insert the data using a `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yup, that seems to do it, I'll just use java to do the processing and feed it into prepared statements, Thanks!